# Git's Version of Update to HEAD

Tags: git

I'm a newbie at git and want to understand how to collaborate with a few friends on a project using git. My problem is trying to understand how to "updated to HEAD (like in SVN)" in git. I understand git's a bit different, and I would appreciate any help.

So consider this situation. There is Person A and Person B. Person A changes a file by making 1 addition. He then performs:

1. Commit's on his own branch
2. Switch to master
3. pull origin master
4. git merge personAbranch
5. git push origin master

So, so far, this works, as on GitHub the repository has been updated with Person A's changes.

Now, assume that Person B during this whole time has been making changes of his own as well. He too, makes 1 addition. What should Person B do "update to HEAD" so that he can commit his changes as well. What Person B has tried is...

1. commiting his own change to his own branch.
2. Switching to master
3. git pull origin master
4. git merge master ian.

On the fourth line, he always gets a complaint of a conflict. Why?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If git is complaining about a conflict, it means that person A and person B (could his name be Ian? ;) have modified the same file and the changes, well, conflict.  Either the file is a binary file, for which git can never resolve two different modifications, or it's a text file and the two modifications touch the same set of lines.

You will have to resolve the conflict.  You can use `git mergetool` to help with this.

(Conflicts are not unique to git.  They can happen with Subversion, too, for the same sort of reason.)

Comment: Thanks for the help Ken Thomases. I think when Ian and I tested it, I would have a file that would say "Test file." For me, I would add an additional line that says "Alex's Addition." Ian would simultaneously add a line on his computer that says "Ian's addition." I was hoping that git could merge the too, but I guess since they are on the same lines, then it won't work. However, would it help if Ian maybe placed his additional line further down the file (say, press Enter a bunch of times) so that it does not conflict with my line? Would git be able to merge the two?

Comment: No.  For example, how could git know if your line was meant to go immediately after the original line or after Ian's additions?